# Prepopulate SharePoint Addin Library with Data

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin

I'm creating a SharePoint Hosted Addin on SharePoint Online. I have added a List to my project based on the Assets Library instance.

Can someone tell me how I can prepopulate the list with some data? I understand that if it were an ordinary list, without a file associated with it, I could achieve this using  tags in the elements.xml file. However, how does this work if I want my assets library to have content when it is installed?

I'd like the library to have some images in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a module to your Add In project and the modify the xml file generated for you to look something like this:

```
 <Module Name="MyImages" Url="SiteAssets">
    <File Path="MyImages\myimage1.png" Url="myimage1.png" ReplaceContent="TRUE" />
    <File Path="MyImages\myimage2.png" Url="myimage2.png" ReplaceContent="TRUE" />
  </Module>
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked. I just had to change the URL value to "Lists/MyList" and it was able to prepopulate my app list with the files. Cheers!